# Need help proving the standard topology is a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Define $$\tau_s = \{ U \subseteq X| \forall x \in U, \exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } B_\delta(x) \subseteq U\}$$

> Show $\tau_s$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$

**Can someone check if my proof is correct and help me resolve a problem with showing finite intersection?**

1. $\varnothing$ vacuously lies in $\tau_s$. Let $U_x$ be an open set for each $x$ that lies in $X$, then $\bigcup_{x \in X} U_x = X$. Arbitrary union of opens is open, hence $X$ is open.
2. Let $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^n$  be a finite subcollection of sets in $X$, then let $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n U_i$, since $x \in U_i$, $U_i$ is open, then $\exists \delta_i>0$ for each $x \in U_i$$\ldots$

*Here I want to say that we wish to pick $\delta = \min\{\delta_i\}_{i=1}^n$ so that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^n U_i$, but it is not clear (graphically) that such $\delta$ would work. What is the way to continue the proof from $\ldots$*

3. Let $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ be an arbitrary subcollection of sets in $X$, then $\forall x \in U_\alpha,  \exists \delta_\alpha >0$ s.t. $B_{\delta_\alpha} \subseteq U_\alpha \implies B_{\delta_{\alpha}}(x) \subseteq \bigcup_\limits{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha, \forall x \in\bigcup_\limits{\alpha \in I} U_\alpha  $

*One more thing, can $X$ be any metric space?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your finite collection $U_i$. If $x \in U_i$ for all $i$, you have $\delta_i$ such that $B(x, \delta_i) \subset U_i$. Now take $\delta = \min \delta_i$. Since $\delta \leq \delta_i$, for all $i$, $B(x,\delta) \subset B(x, \delta_i) \subset U_i$ for all $i$. Thus $B(x,\delta) \subset \cap_i U_i$.

Comment: Otherwise the proof seems ok. And yes $X$ can be any metric space.